# Finder does not sort correctly in mavericks

Tags: macos, finder

I have both 'sort by' and 'arrange by' sorted as last opened and still finder is not showing the files and folders correctly.

e.g., I have some documents made in 2014 but finder shows those documents as if they were made in 2013. Even 'last opened' shows them in 2013! I am pretty sure that the dates are correct because those documents are from my bank and they didn't exists at all in 2013.

When I put or open a file at a certain date in a sub-folder, why is the date last opened of the 'master-folder' not affected?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't update the folder opened date unless you open it in its own window. Just revealing it in a list view will not refresh the date.

Before…
[image]

During…
[image]

After…
[image]

Neither does adding a file to a folder refresh the opened date…

[image]

Comment: I think it's very odd that I have to open the list view and then open the folder to have the dat last opened changed. I work from the column view and from there I go top down through the folders to get the appropriate file. When I open the file the date last opened of the file and the sub-folder where it stands are changed, but not the date of the top-folder. That's very odd. If I had to go every time in the list view it would give a lot of more work.

Comment: Can you explain why a file which could not exist in 2013 is still being showed in 2013. See screen below at file 'Rekeningoverzicht_201402.pdf'.

Comment: Sorry, I can't upload a screenshot. How of you do that in this system?

Comment: Upload to somewhere like flickr, imgur etc & add the link to your question. Someone with the required rep will add it for you

Comment: the link to the screenshot: http://imgur.com/cK3TPtl