# Why are my Mavericks Finder folders arranged by the wrong year?

Tags: macos, finder

I upgraded to Mavericks ages ago, but only just noticed this problem. Having arranged and sorted a folder by date modified, using icons, all items in the folder are listed as the wrong year. I have items grouped as being "Today", that's correct! But I then have "2013" items (which were all modified in 2014, I checked with Get Info) and "2012" items (which were all modified in 2013, again I checked them.

Why is this happening? How do I fix this?

Comment: see if anything in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167616/finder-does-not-sort-correctly-in-mavericks?rq=1 may help

Comment: Thanks, @Tetsujin! This is my first post in "AskDifferent" so I don't know what's been covered much yet...

Comment: Welcome - idk if there's a 'fix' in there, but there may be some explanation

Comment: Thanks - the other post had an answer that didn't seem to work for me...